# Retrieve data from database to multiple textbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, textbox

When I retrieve data from my Access database to a multiline `TextBox`, it shows all my data in the same line. In the `DataGridView` everything is fine and shows line by line. How to make my textboxes to show data line by line as well?

```
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from data where [ID] like(" + textBox9.Text + ")";
cmd.Connection = con;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = reader["Target Name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: how your data looks like? maybe you want to split it?

Comment: you can separate lines by adding `"\r\n"` or `Environment.NewLine`. On a side note, you must have a look to [Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;

textBox1.Text += reader["Target Name"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Set `MultiLine` property to true and a new line while setting `textBox1.Text` by adding `Environment.NewLine` at the end.

Please don't use `SELECT *`, you can use `SELECT Col1, Col2...`

Also please use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Please us `using` with the SQL connection

Comment: its same bro same error show data all in one line ex   07701442233
07705552233

Comment: all my data is string

Answer (score 0):

This should give the TextBox a Grid/Table appearance:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = reader.getString(0)+"\t"+reader.getString(1)+"\r\n"; //in the case the table 'data' has 2 columns
}
```